# Logging into instance created from AMI with PasswordAuthentication set to yes in sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Linux instance, where I have enabled Password based authentication. So, when I try to login with my user using ssh, I simply enter my password and I can login.

Now, I created an AMI from this running instance and launched it. After, it starts running, I try to log into that instance with the same username and password. However, I get `Permission denied (publickey).` error when I do this.

I tried to run this in the launch script, but it doesn't help.

```
repo_upgrade: none
```

I am pretty sure it used to work this way for old versions of Amazon Linux instances. Is there a way to make this work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the following:
 `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/00_defaults.cfg  -> "ssh_pwauth: true"`